# jQuery BlockUI: Is it possible to run a function after a user hits the "enter" key?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, modal-dialog, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to create a very minimal and simple modal dialog that just displays a textarea.

Goals:

- If the user hits the "esc" key, it'll disappear (and the text input is ignored)
- If the user inputs text and hits the "enter" key, a function that takes the input is run (called "postText(userinput)")

I'm wondering if I can use jQuery BlockUI: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos.

However, I'm not sure how to actually close a dialog based on esc, or run a function if the user hits enter.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
$('#txtValue').keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // The Enter key was pressed
        postText($(this).val());   
    }
});
```

You should how ever use the `form.submit` event instead of listening for the `enter` key.

```
if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    // The Esc key was pressed
    $('#dialog').hide();
}
```

Also see these for more info;

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+esc+key

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+enter+key

Answer (score 4):

Close dialog on `ESC`, just add an `keyup` listener to `document` and call `$.unblockUI` if the key code is equal to `27`.

```
​​$(document).on('keyup', ​​​function(e) {
  if (e.which === 27) { // Escape key
    $.unblockUI();
  }
});​
```

For the form, just add an event listener to the input field in the dialog. It's basically the same.

```
​​$('#the-input').on('keyup', ​​​function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) { // Enter key
    // AJAX maybe?
    $.post('your/url', { data: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
      $.unblockUI();            
    });
  }
});​
```

**Edit**

You assign those listeners after the DOM has been loaded. So your loaded script file would contain:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code from the two listings above here

    // Trigger blockUI by click on an link for example
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.blockUI({ message: $('#your-form') });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! i'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but what is the difference between #the-input and #your-form. i have a div with id your-form with the input field. what is the purpose of #the-input?

Comment: `#the-input` should be the id assigned to your text input field which you want to be sent on enter. `#your-form` should be the id assigned to your `<form>` element. Passing `$('#your-form')` to blockUI should display the whole form inside the modal.

Comment: although i think in your second code block we should compare e to 13

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```
("#yourInput").keyup(function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 13: # enter
    # logic
    case 27: # esc
    # logic
    }
})
```

Comment: hm, i'm unclear where i actually put this code. is it somehow embedded in the $.blockUI call? thank you!

Comment: See my answer. You assign those listeners after the DOM has been loaded.